# How to implement a system call fork ()?

Tags: fork, system-calls

As we know, every process will call fork () in Linux. It will return 0 or 1 as normal or -1 to represent error. But, I don't know how to make a variable that can have two values at the same time. Can you give me some hits to help me to implement it?

Comment: Why do you think you need a variable that stores two values?

Comment: Looks like title should be "how to use `fork()` to have different values in child and parent processes", and not "how to implement `fork()`"...

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one variable that has two values. There are two variables, one in the parent and one in the child, and each has only a single value. The `fork` call returns twice. The process acts as if it was copied.

If you're interested in learning how `fork` is implemented, I'd suggest you start by looking at the actual implementation. Consider:

```
bool is_child()
{
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    // some system call that returns twice (like 'clone')
    return (getpid() == pid);
}
```

Here you have a function whose return value depends on which process it returns from. If you do `j = is_child();` the variable `j` will be `false` in the parent and `true` in the child.

Here's a full working example:

```
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    bool my_fork()
    {
        pid_t pid = getpid();
        fork(); // we ignore the return value
        return pid == getpid();
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        bool j = my_fork();
        if (j)
            printf("parent\n");
        else
            printf("child\n");
        _exit (0);
    }
```